# Nested std::conditional_t failed but using class specialization tricks OK? Why?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

I have a traits class to call some invokables. It can accept whether `range` parameter or not.

My code is below.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename PrototypeClassType, typename... Args>
struct InvokeResultTraits {
  static constexpr bool is_invocable_with_range_v =
      std::is_invocable_v<PrototypeClassType, int, Args...>;

  static constexpr bool is_invocable_without_range_v =
      std::is_invocable_v<PrototypeClassType, Args...>;

  using invoke_result_t = std::conditional_t<
      is_invocable_with_range_v,
      std::invoke_result_t<PrototypeClassType, int, Args...>,
      std::conditional_t<is_invocable_without_range_v,
                         std::invoke_result_t<PrototypeClassType, Args...>,
                         void>>;

  static inline auto Invoke(const PrototypeClassType &p, int range,
                            Args &&...args) -> invoke_result_t {
    if constexpr (is_invocable_with_range_v) {
      return std::invoke(p, range, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else if constexpr (is_invocable_without_range_v) {
      return std::invoke(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else {
      static_assert(!sizeof(PrototypeClassType),
                    "No suitable operator() const");
    }
  }
};

// Use traits to perform a call
template <typename Prototype, typename... Args>
auto bar(const Prototype &p, int range, Args &&...args) {
  return InvokeResultTraits<Prototype, Args...>::Invoke(
      p, range, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

However, the `std::conditional_t` will cause a compiler error

> `error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<Foo1, bool>' void>>`

How can you explain the error?

As a workaround, I've used a class specialization trick do the same thing, which works.

```cpp
template <bool CanInvokeWithInt, bool CanInvokeWithoutInt,
          typename PrototypeClassType, typename... Args>
struct InvokeResultType {
  using type = void;
};

template <typename PrototypeClassType, typename... Args>
struct InvokeResultType<true, false, PrototypeClassType, Args...> {
  using type = std::invoke_result_t<PrototypeClassType, int, Args...>;
};

template <typename PrototypeClassType, typename... Args>
struct InvokeResultType<false, true, PrototypeClassType, Args...> {
  using type = std::invoke_result_t<PrototypeClassType, Args...>;
};


template <typename PrototypeClassType, typename... Args>
struct InvokeResultTraits {
  // same as above ...

  using invoke_result_t =
      typename InvokeResultType<is_invocable_with_range_v,
                                is_invocable_without_range_v,
                                PrototypeClassType, Args...>::type;

  // same as above ...
};
```

Somebody may notice that `InvokeResultTraits::invoke_result_t` is useless. But the helper class also has a ability to get the result type.

[Demo at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eTbaxjh8q)

Answer (score 4):

For `conditional_t`, regardless of whether the condition is met or not, the two corresponding types will *always* be instantiated. So when one of the types is invalid, a hard error occurs.

This is different from class specialization, which will *only* instantiate specializations that meet the conditions.

One workaround is to determine the result type by invoking a lambda containing different compile-time branch conditions

```
using invoke_result_t = decltype([] {
  if constexpr (is_invocable_with_range_v)
    return std::invoke_result<PrototypeClassType, int, Args...>{};
  else if constexpr (is_invocable_without_range_v)
    return std::invoke_result<PrototypeClassType, Args...>{};
  else
    return std::type_identity<void>{};
 }())::type;
```

Or you can just declare the return type of `Invoke()` as `decltype(auto)`, which allows the compiler to automatically deduce the return type and remove the redundant `invoke_result_t` type alias.

```
static inline auto Invoke(const PrototypeClassType &p, int range,
                          Args &&...args) -> decltype(auto) {
```

Comment: Why are `type_identity` and `::type` needed here?

Comment: @WeijunZhou The type deduced by `invoke_result_t` may not be default-constructible.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the lack of short-circuiting. `std::invoke_result` is not going to contain a `::type` if the invocation isn't possible, and you're always accessing it through `std::invoke_result_t`.

You can make the first solution work with some small adjustments:

```cpp
using invoke_result_t = typename std::conditional_t<
    is_invocable_with_range_v,
    std::invoke_result<PrototypeClassType, int, Args...>,
    std::conditional_t<is_invocable_without_range_v,
                       std::invoke_result<PrototypeClassType, Args...>,
                       std::enable_if<true>>>::type;
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hcaGh1aPM)*

`std::conditional_t` is now used to select the trait type, not the `::type` within the trait type.
The `::type` of the trait type is only accessed once at the very end, which avoids early failure.

---

*Note: `std::enable_if<true>` is simply a way of defining a trait where `::type = void`. If you were using C++20, `std::type_identity<void>` would be more appropriate.*